# Transferring rows from a table to join similar rows in the same table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets [roster](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ozU8IA3jqK-XB5W4DBeIb2wbijQvKRk7trHMV8tXP8/edit?usp=sharing).  The link is a minimised version.  In reality, each block corresponds to a fortnight, with subsequent fortnights placed below each other. (I don't have permission to provide an image of the roster).

For equity and fatigue management, I am keeping a tally of on-calls rostered.  In particular, I am counting the number of times someone has worked on-call in any capacity for a certain number of days in a row.

I am able to do this by manually creating an array first and then solving for days in a row (this example is for 2 days in a row):

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF((len(split(CONCATENATE(SIGN(MMULT({1,1,1},--IF(REGEXMATCH({$B$7:$D$9, $B$17:$D$19}, F5),1,0))),),0))),"=2"))
```

This has limitations, as other lines may be added to the roster for varying reasons, breaking the manually built array.  So I am trying to automate the creation of an array.

I am able to extract all the on-call data using a query:

```
=QUERY(A:D, "select B,C,D where A contains 'On Call'",0)
```

But to follow the manual solution I have above, I need each on-call line to remain as a single row.  I feel like there should be a simple solution where I can append each "fortnight" to the same corresponding row.  So in other words, instead of the query returning a table of 14 columns with 26 (fortnights per year) x 3 (rows of on-call per fortnight), I get a table of 3 rows with 14 x 26 columns.  Alternatively, I could accept the query result and then manipulate the table to the 3 rows and 14 x 26 columns.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any function or combination of functions that will do this automatically.  I can make a macro to do it, but as the roster is not set for the entire year, the macro only works for a particular moment in time.

I don't have sufficient javascript skills (at the moment) to write a custom function.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have found a solution via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469837/how-to-combine-rows-with-same-id-in-google-sheets?rq=1)